# Melhor desempenho/performance: Smarty, Twig ou algum outro?

Tags: php, desempenho, twig, template

Embora no geral os sistemas de *templates* para PHP são utilizados com outros objetivos, como por exemplo separar regras de negócio, etc. Qual deles fornece um melhor desempenho para o carregamento/performance de site (ou aplicação web)?

Atualmente, qual destes oferece maior vantagem neste ponto, e seria esta a melhor forma para otimização ou existem outras alternativas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty é mais rápido, se é que isto importa. Concluí isto vendo [essa comparação](http://umumble.com/blogs/php/smarty-vs-twig%3A-performance/). Claro que eu sei olhar para estes testes como algo limitado. O teste é válido para estas condições, nas suas condições pode acontecer algo diferente, depende do ambiente, do código, das práticas adotadas. Eu sequer sei se a pessoa que realizou estes testes sabe usar ambos corretamente e tem interesse em divulgar dados desfavoráveis ao seu mecanismo preferido.

Então instale os dois, aprenda usá-los, faça o que precisa em ambos da melhor forma que conseguir e meça o desempenho. Este é o único resultado que você pode confiar.

Provavelmente você está pedindo para outras pessoas fazerem o teste para você porque, mesmo inconscientemente, você sabe que não compensa fazer o teste, a diferença será mínima, principalmente porque você já está usando uma linguagem que não preza pela performance. Se um fosse tão mais rápido que outro e isso fosse importante, o lento, se não estivesse morto, pelo menos seria considerado por toda comunidade como algo inviável para quem quer performance. E isto está longe de ser verdade. Embora a comunidade específica já aceite certa lentidão como normal.

Outra coisa importante. Se precisa de performance não use nenhum deles, porque ambos adicionam tempo de execução trazendo resultados que muitos questionam. Use um deles ou outra coisa que facilite seu trabalho pela facilidade, não pela performance.

Comment: Agradeço pelas boas observações a respeito, onde o meu objetivo é sim a performance de site, pois o foco são sites para serem acessados  também via celular, levando em consideração uma internet lenta por parte dos usuários.