# O que é as tags {} no meio do html

Tags: php, html

Em uma página web com extensão `.html` não é possível usar as tags `php` certo?

Mas vi em algumas páginas `html` códigos do tipo `{CONTEUDO}` que exibe um texto definido em um arquivo `php` `'$tpl->CONTEUDO = "texto"`'.
Mas não entendo exatamente o uso dessas tags `{ }` para mostrar algo do `php`, dá pra mostrar uma variável ou uma constante desse mesmo modo?

Código php:

```
    require("banco.php");
require("classes/funcoes.php");
require("classes/String.php");
require("classes/Template.class.php");

$tpl = new Template("html/template.html");

//-- Google ****
$tpl->PG_TITLE = "RaÃ§Ãµes Catarinense";
$tpl->PG_DESCRIPTION = "RaÃ§Ãµes Catarinense ";
$tpl->PG_KEYWORDS = "RaÃ§Ãµes Catarinense ";
$tpl->PG_CANONICAL = "http://www." . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
//-- Google ****
// Adicionando mais um arquivo HTML
$tpl->addFile("CONTEUDO", "html/produto.html");

$tpl->CSS = "produto";
$tpl->ATIVO_home = 'class="ativo"';

$tpl->PAGINA_ATIVA = "produto-body";
```

Na página produto.html esses atributos são exibidos assim `'{PAGINA_ATIVA}'`

Comment: Só com isso é meio complicado responder pode ser um template definido pelo usuario ou até mesmo do CI ... se tiver o código completo facilita.

Comment: Isso é muito provavelmente a utilização de templates, por exemplo, [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php), ou então [Lightcandy](https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy).

Comment: Não consegui entender direito, mas parece que na página php é usado uma classe '$tpl = new Template("html/template.html");' e ele define os atributos da classe no arquivo php, no arquivo de html eles mostra esses atributos usando essas tags { }

Comment: vc tem esse código pode adicionar na pergunta? [exemplo do CI](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html)

Comment: O que eu estou procurando e não acho é se dá pra usar essas tags {  } para exibir variaveis ou constantes no html. Ou seja, se tem algo jeito de exibir php dentro de um arquivo .html

Comment: Não, arquivos html não são processados pelo PHP, pode acontecer dessa marcação(`{TITULO}`) ser substituida por um arquivo php com `str_replace()` por exemplo, isso também pode ser feito com javascript com algumas diferenças.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81607/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, o php pode ser escrito também com arquivos .tpl.

O tpl está mais para um Smarty File, onde ele serve de transitor de comandos, e eles (comandos PHP) podem ser chamados no tpl.html através de `{php} comandos {/php}` por exemplo

Para fazer a chamada no inicio do Header, você utiliza `{include file='arquivoX.tpl' p="index"}`

Realmente você não consegue chamar comandos PHP direto no .html pois ele não passaria pelo interpretador que gera a página, então para funcionar deveria ser utilizado ou arquivos .php `<?php ?>` ou .tpl `{php} {/php}`

Você consegue nos mostrar este código da página para tentarmos entender melhor?

Comment: eu editei a pergunta :)

Comment: já vi esse tipo de arquivo tpl, mas nunca tinha visto um site feito dessa forma. Achei muito estranho ele ter um arquivo produto.php e um produto.html e assim com todas as páginas, tipo porque não colocar o html junto com o php?

Answer (score 1):

Isto é um template. Provavelmente outra página [php](/questions/tagged/php) está fazendo um `include` com esta página [html](/questions/tagged/html) e fazendo `replace` nos conteúdo que tem chaves pelo valor da variável.